# Using Microsoft translator similar to how Google's widget works?

Tags: javascript, translation

Google translate provides a very simple solution of adding a dropdown to translate an entire page:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp

It looks like Bing used to provide a similar tool before it was merged into Microsoft's cloud service. Is this possible to do anymore with Microsoft? I only see them providing REST endpoints, would it be much more difficult to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/text-translation-overview#get-started-with-text-translation) there are only two options:

1. REST API
2. SDK

This requires good amount of changes to provide widget like behaviour at client side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).